# Time to do something about datascience stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, cross-validated, stack-overflow

I was very interested when I found this branch of StackOverflow, and initially the questions and answers seemed rare, but reasonably interesting.

Lately I see, for example, 4 out of 11 active questions being asked by a single user, on trivial steps of a textbook stuff. I also see extremely general useless questions (what is data science, how to become data scientist).

I personally would be interested in the professional part of some combination of cross validated, data science and the algorithms tag on stackoverflow, in order to see how professional people solve problems.. Maybe the questions by all kinds of beginners could be asked in a single big stackoverflow.com.

Comment: One issue is the large overlap with stats SE.

Answer (score 6):

I was involved on the Open Data SE from its early ages. We had the same problem there. What we forget is that both Open Data and Data Science are in beta version. And Data Science has really low statistics.

The most important tasks that WE can do to improve the quality of the website, is to bring more traffic from Google search. How we did it?

If one knows a great example of a possible question + answer on the subject, he makes the question, wait for a few days and if no-one give a decent answer, he/she gives the one that is better.

The results are amazing, because we will end up in a short period with great quality questions + answers. Not only quantity.

Answer (score 4):

I know I am not an `avid` user. My reputation is not even worth mentioning. I would however, consider myself an `engaged` user. Again, this is subjective at this stage without a common definition of the word.

I believe, there is some value in a `beginner` tag across overlapping streams and so is the relevance of DS SE. Some of the questions that have been asked on SE (my comments are specific to R), can very well be answered by looking into documentation. However, I always found the responses here to be much more relevant than the standard documentation and generic examples.

Answer (score 3):

-- Edit, following comment --

How much appetite is there to continue DS.SE? I see the value, but I don't know if there is the support, i.e. a body of people who are interested in DS practice and who are able to answer questions, but also enough people who are able to ask sufficient questions to make the site worth visitng.

The [stats for DS.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55053/data-science) are interesting, but is there a trending DS type analytic that we could see ;). Today there are 2,060 site visits ... what is the unique visitor number per day?

Please note, I'm not meaning to have a go at anyone, just seeing if there is any engagement with my comment, if there is, then I'll probably throw myself into contributing solidly.

Comment: _but I don't know if there is the support_ <-- What do you mean by that?  _ unique visitor number_ <-- Number of unique visitors per day

Comment: By "support" I mean, are there a significant body of users who are engaged with the site to ask and answer questions. I'll update my answer for clarity re unique visitors ...

Comment: The _avid users_ count says that there indeed are a significant amount of users interested in the site :)

Comment: An "avid user" is a "user with at least 200 reputation", That's what the on-hover tooltip says, which matches the detail box on the right hand side of it. Some of these people may not have visited for ages...I'd be interested in how many people are actively engaged with the site. I might do some data collection and analysis ... !

Answer (score -2):

What about merging **opendata** with **datascience** -- two beta groups that could both benefit... is this possible? It appears there may be mechanisms for [proposal mergers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69651/tools-for-merging-proposals-on-area-51) but what about betas, can it be done? is it desirable?

Comment: DS SE is doing really good as a site now [stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55053/data-science). So, pretty confident that it has a nice place for itself in the network. And, I see them(OD and DS) as very different sites (almost `mutually exclusive`). So, maybe not a good idea :)